# Jquery- change background color and selection fields

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery table with the id="myTable",

**I want to achieve two things.**

1. At the moment just a click on the "select" button is choosing a certain table row. I want that you can click everywhere inside the table row to select this one, not just a click on the button.
2. The background color of the selected table row should immediately change after click on the "select" button or the table row itself.

This is my script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
  $("#myTable").on('click', '.btnSelect', 'tr', function() {
    // get the current row
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

    var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").html(); // get current row 1st table cell TD value
    var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").html(); // get current row 2nd table cell TD value
    var col3 = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").html(); // get current row 3rd table cell  TD value
    var output1 = col1;
    var output2 = col2;
    var output3 = "<?php echo $id; ?>";
    var output4 = "<?php echo $status; ?>";

    $('#myTable tr').click(function(e) {
      $('#myTable tr').removeClass('rowcolorbg');
      $(this).addClass('rowcolorbg');
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax-callback.php",
      data: {
        output1: output1,
        output2: output2,
        output3: output3,
        output4: output4
      },

      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using four params, use three instead. The target selector should be comma separated, just like you would do in CSS:

```
$("#myTable").on("click", ".btnSelect, tr", function() {
```

Also don't use click events inside click events.

All in all:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
  $("#myTable").on("click", ".btnSelect, tr", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    const $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    $row.siblings().removeClass("rowcolorbg"); // Other <tbody> TR elements
    $row.addClass("rowcolorbg");

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax-callback.php",
      data: {
        output1: $row.find("td:eq(0)").html(),
        output2: $row.find("td:eq(1)").html(),
        output3: "<?= $id ?>",
        output4: "<?= $status ?>"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
  
});
```

Quick demo:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
  $("#myTable").on("click", "tr", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    const $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    $row.siblings().removeClass("rowcolorbg"); // Other <tbody> TR elements
    $row.addClass("rowcolorbg");

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax-callback.php",
      data: {
        output1: $row.find("td:eq(0)").html(),
        output2: $row.find("td:eq(1)").html(),
        output3: "<?= $id ?>",
        output4: "<?= $status ?>"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.rowcolorbg td {
  background: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>A</td><td>123</td><td>OK</td><td><button type="button" class="btnSelect">SEL</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td><td>B</td><td>654</td><td>OK</td><td><button type="button" class="btnSelect">SEL</button></td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table> 


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, now everything is clickable within a row. for the background-color change.

Comment: @Retros you're interested in `.siblings()` - See my edit above.